# Why we couldn't say $\int \sin(\ln x) dx = -\cos(\ln x)+c$ according to the formula $\int \sin(u) = -\cos(u)+c$?

Tags: integration

Why we couldn't say $\int \sin(\ln x)dx  = -\cos(\ln x)+c$ according to the formula $\int\sin(u)  = -\cos(u)+c$ ?

Comment: If the integration was wrt $ln(x)$, then one could definitely say that. But if the integration is being done wrt $x$ , one cant say that.

Comment: Use your differentials! ($\mathrm{d}?$)

Comment: Maybe the most direct answer is that the formula $$\int\sin(u)  = -\cos(u)+c$$ means *nothing*, and that the correct formula is $$\int\sin(u)du  = -\cos(u)+c.$$ Now, plugging $$u=\ln x$$ in this, yields $$du=\frac1xdx,$$ hence $$\int\sin(\ln x)dx \ne\int\sin(\ln x)\frac1xdx=\int \sin(u)du= -\cos(u)+c.$$

Answer (score 4):

By the same reason we cannot say
$$
(\sin(\ln x))'=\cos(\ln x).
$$
The chain rule tells us that
$$
(\sin(\ln x))'=\cos(\ln x)\,\frac1x.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you use the substitution $u = ln(x)$, you must change the variable of integration.

$du =  \frac{dx}{x}$ and the integral becomes $\int sin(ln(x)) dx = \frac{1}{x} \int sin(u) du$

Edit - misread the natural logarithm as L n x

Answer (score 0):

we get $\int \sin(\ln(x))dx=-1/2\,\cos \left( \ln  \left( x \right)  \right) x+1/2\,\sin \left( 
\ln  \left( x \right)  \right) x
+C$

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate  $-\cos(\ln x)+c $ to see that chain rule comes into play giving you a different result.